# How to get an id number from a row in a database through a $_GET of a different row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, get

I want to make it so the url shows the cat_name of the page the user is on. Currently it is category.php?id=2 or

```
category.php?id=' . $row['cat_id'] . '
```

I want to make it category.php?title=Soccer or

```
category.php?title=' . $row['cat_name'] . '
```

However, when I replace that line, it causes problems on the other page.

The page category.php is:

```
<?php
//category.php
include 'connect.php';


//first select the category based on $_GET['cat_id']
$sql = "SELECT
        cat_name,
        cat_id,
        cat_description
    FROM
        categories
    WHERE
        cat_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) ."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
echo 'The category could not be displayed, please try again later.' .     mysql_error();
}
else
{
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo 'This category does not exist.';
}
else
{
    //display category data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo '<h2>Topics in &prime;' . $row['cat_name'] . '&prime; category</h2><br />';
    }

    //do a query for the topics
$sql = "SELECT topic_id, topic_subject, topic_date, topic_cat
    FROM topics
    JOIN categories
    ON topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id
    WHERE cat_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if(!$result)
    {
        echo 'The topics could not be displayed, please try again later.';
    }
    else
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
        {
            echo 'There are no topics in this category yet.';
        }
        else
        {
            //prepare the table
            echo '<table border="1">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Topic</th>
                    <th>Created at</th>
                  </tr>';   

            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {               
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td class="leftpart">';
                        echo '<h3><a href="topic.php?id=' .     $row['topic_id'] . '">' . $row['topic_subject'] . '</a><br /><h3>';
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td class="rightpart">';
                        echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['topic_date']));
                    echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
    }
}
}

?>
```

The issue is that when i replace the url, it makes it so the second $sql (the one just below: do a query for the topics) not work. I want to make it so the sql works with the change to the url.

I want to change the cat_id to cat_name, but when i do, it comes up with the error that it did not work. So the issue is that the sql needs the GET to be with the cat_id while i want the url to have the cat_name instead. What do i change in the sql query to make it possible to use the cat_name and still have it work?

Hope that's a better explanation of the problem. Tell me if you need more info
Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: What is the other table name?  And what is the primary key of the other table (the one that matches `topic_cat` from `topics`?

Comment: other table is categories, the primary key of the table categories is cat_id

Comment: jedwards, could you write it out with the information provided now? (with the ON section too if it applies)

Comment: Just did.  If you get an error, please post it.

Comment: i see what youre trying to do. and i think that my question was misleading... the issue is that 'title' is in the url, and its the same as cat_name (in categories table). However, what i need to call is the row cat_id (in categories table). The cat_id is the same as topic_cat (in topics table). How do i relate the topic_cat to the cat_id and then the cat_id to the cat_name?

Comment: I edited my answer, try that.

Comment: still didnt work... but i replaced the cat_name with cat_id. and replaced title with id in the url. it works like that. So is it possible to the cat_id with cat_name and make it work? any other ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include what you have now, as well as any errors / what you're getting now vs. what you want?

Comment: yeah ill rewrite it and include all the code and more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) syntax seems to be what you want.

In general its something like

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.key = table2.key
WHERE <conditions>
```

The `ON` tells the database which keys should be used to "match" up the rows.  The `<table>.<field>` syntax allows you to specify which table a field comes from, in case the tables contain the same field name.

So you might adapt your query to something like

```
$sql = "SELECT topic_id, topic_subject, topic_date, topic_cat
        FROM topics
        JOIN categories
        ON topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id
        WHERE cat_name = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
$sql = "SELECT  
                topic_id,
                topic_subject,
                topic_date,
                topic_cat
            FROM
                topics
            JOIN
                other_table
            ON
                topics.topic_cat = other_table.id
            AND
                other_table.title = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title'])."'";
```

The reason why this would work is that it would select the above four fields from a joined table of topic_cat and other_table using the foreign keys of both tables. From this it would select the data where other_table.title = the $_GET['title']..

Comment: You should add a little note about why you think this works, especially the `<table>.<field>` syntax.

Comment: nope still not working, unless i just typed something in wrong... sorry im new to foreign keys and this level of php and sql

Comment: I think you're missing the `ON` section

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  t.topic_id, t.topic_subject, t.topic_date, t.topic_cat, c.cat_id, c.cat_name
FROM
  topics as t
INNER JOIN
  categories as c
WHERE
  topic_cat = ". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']) ."
    AND
      t.topic_cat = c.cat_id
```